# Can I use "quickly" to politely ask for preliminary information?

Tags: formality, politeness

When, e.g., I receive a job opportunity which might or might not match my requirements, I often find myself responding with

> "... Thank you for bringing this role to my attention. Before we
> proceed, could you **quickly** confirm if this role is ..."

Quickly, as used in my native language, means "*without much formality*", i.e. "*let's just set this straight before we continue with due formalities, exchanging CVs and what not*".

Is it used and understood the same way in english, or would it imply some sort of urgency or ASAP!-expectation?

Comment: Is this for communicating with prospective employers/recruiters? In such a case I wouldn't use an adverb at all. Saying, "Before we proceed" in itself communicates the sense of tentativeness or preparatory work. I would be reluctant to tell someone to do something "quickly" if you have no idea how much work they would be doing - you don't know if what you're asking is trivial to find out. In other less formal contexts, it would be fine to say "could you quickly send me..." or "could you send me a quick..." but it's not right here.

Comment: Quickly here means “as fast as you can”. “Can you straightaway confirm …”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- '*Quickly*' ([i.e.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/quickly) "*with speed; rapidly; very soon*") puts some pressure on the process, and therefore the addressee: it indeed implies urgency.
  I would not consider this a polite request, as you are already asking someone else to put some amount of effort into something that benefits only you (at this point, at least).

  If politeness is more important than urgency, I'd suggest leaving out any adjective:

  > Before we proceed, could you confirm if [/that] this role is ...

  And leave it up to the receiver to deal with as they please. In case of a job opportunity, they likely are able to appreciate the time sensitivity.
- Alternatively, you can ask them to "*glance over*" the job description to see whether it is a good fit for you:

  - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glance):

    > - to give a quick short look:
    >   *Could you glance over/through this letter and see if it's alright?*
  - [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/glance):

    > - *(intr; foll by over, through, etc)* to look over briefly: *to glance through a report*
  - [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/glance+over):

    > - To look at someone or something quickly and perfunctorily.
    > - to examine someone or something very quickly.
    >   *I only glanced over the papers. They look okay to me. The doctor glanced over the injured woman and called for an ambulance.*

Comment: Quickly can mean "soon," but in this context it just means "rapidly," i.e. it indicates that the addressee does not need to spend too much time on the task.

Comment: @alphabet you're right, but I think it depends on the interpretation of the reader with which meaning they go.

Answer (score 2):

**Quickly** -> with speed. It is the wrong word. (To me this "quickly" always implies "I may argue the small print with you later if I accept it.")

Where there is a choice, it is usually "confirm **whether**", not confirm **if** (which is conditional), but here, it is "confirm **that**"

You seem to be asking

Before we proceed, could you confirm, in brief, that this role is ..."

Comment: "Could you send me a quick report/note/email..." is very common in my experience, and "could you quickly send me the figures..." is only a little less common, although it does require that it genuinely is a quick thing to do. Whether what the OP wants is actually quick is another matter.

Comment: *Quickly* is indeed the wrong word when telling a stranger to rush on your behalf. Next, tell that to a cop at a traffic stop and watch alacrity increase, but not in the desired direction.

Comment: I would suggest _briefly_ rather than _quickly_.

Comment: @KateBunting But one doesn't really "briefly confirm" :)

Comment: @Joachim - I was assuming that what needed to be confirmed was some point that needed a quick/brief 'yes/no' answer!

Comment: As I suggested - use "in brief" - it differs in nuance from "briefly."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this usage of "quickly" is common; it means that you should state something briefly, without excessive detail or irrelevant information.

[Here's an example from an NPR interview:](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/10407845)

> Sheriff, there was a period in 2005 when Forsyth went through a spate of teenage driving tragedies. **Could you quickly** tell us what happened in that period?

Comment: I agree "quickly" can be used this way to mean "briefly" and can soften the request by implying it will only take a short amount of time. "Can you please do a quick check to see if it is in stock?" "You wouldn't mind if I quickly used the toilet, would you?" However, as stated by others it's probably safer to leave it out of formal emails.

Comment: Why? It's not an informal usage and I don't think anyone would misinterpret it.